# Disable Jenkins checks on feature branch pushes

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a *git repo* with a **master** branch, and different **feature** branches.

I have connected it to *Jenkins*, so it triggers each time there is a **push** or a **pull request**.
I also have a **Jenkins file** with several stages: *build, check1, check2* etc.

I want to disable running the stages when there is a **push** in a **feature** branch. Every push trigger, should run if it is from master.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this when condition on those stages like this for feature branches.

```
stage ('Do not Run stage for feature') {
  when {
    expression { return !env.GIT_BRANCH.contains('feature') }
  }
  steps {
    sh 'echo Hello'
  }
}
```

This above stage only get's executed when it's master branch.

Comment: It works, thanks :) Do you have any idea how to exclude all the stages if the branch is not master. i.e. build, sanity_check, deploy. Without putting the when statement inside each single stage.

Comment: Althought that is a separate question and should be handled in a separate thread, you can use what @Dashrath Mundkar and instead of do it in every stage, do it at script beginning and define a global variable; handle it then as desired

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be using `comparator` as in from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions)

```
when { branch pattern: "feature\\.+", comparator: "REGEXP"}
```